# Difficulty tracking a NullPointerException

Tags: java, dictionary, nullpointerexception, set

Here is the piece of code generating the NPE, please let me know if it is not enough to give you perspective as to what could be going wrong.

I have a map instantiated this way:

`Map<Integer, Set<Long>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Long>>();`

And I'm trying to do the following:

```
long randomLong = methodReturnsRandomLong();
int randomInt = methodReturnsRandomInt();

if(myMap.isEmpty()) { // the map is empty at this point
   myMap.put(randomInt, new HashSet<Long>());
   myMap.get(randomInt).add(randomLong);
}

// Now I want to remove it
myMap.get(randomInt).remove(randomLong);  // Here is what generates the NPE
```

I don't understand what could be causing the NPE.  My guess is using `new HashSet<Long>()` within my `myMap.put()` method is causing it. But I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: As it is, this code doesn't produce a NPE. There's something else you're not telling us.

Comment: @Qwerky there is just so much code that I wasn't sure what all to include  :-/

Comment: My answer below is probably what is actually happening here. But... that is just an educated guess because, as @Qwerky says, not enough information.

Comment: I ran the code, it did work fine for me. Can you also post your methodReturnRandomLong() and methodreturnRandomInt()

Comment: Ru sure that it is going inside the if condition ??

Comment: If I do `new HashSet<Long>()` what exactly am I referencing in memory when I do an add?  I thought that may be the issue.

Comment: When you call `hashset.add` in the code example you provided above, you are referencing the only instance of `hashset` you've created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the map might not be empty, but **not** have an entry for your `randomInt` value.

What you are looking for is:

```
//does a mapping exist for this specific value?
if(!myMap.containsKey(randomInt)){
    myMap.put(randomInt, new Hashset<Long>());
    myMap.get(randomInt).add(randomLong);
}
//now this value will be defined here.
myMap.get(randomInt).remove(randomLong);
```

Calling `map.isEmpty` is just checking that *no* mappings exist. You really want to know whether a mapping exists for the `randomInt` value, not if any mapping exists.

I know you say the map is empty at this point, but I've seen this error a few times before. This is usually the cause in situations similar to this.

Comment: This was my issue!  Thanks (Gosh I feel like such a noob) :(

Comment: That's great to hear! Everybody has to learn sometime. Please remember accept this answer to close this question.